# How can I get a return?

Tags: java, printing, return

I'm writing a program that will read in a line of integers and will print them out in reverse order on separate lines. I've written the code to actually make it, but I'm stuck on how to get it to test it. When I run my code and enter integers it just stops running. How can I make it print them back? Do I need a println somewhere? Here is the code so far. I've added a scanner to the tester class as well as a separator.

**Separator Class**

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Separator {

public Separator(int initialValue){

    value = initialValue;
    while (initialValue / 10 == 0){
        initialValue = initialValue / 10;
        count++;
    }
}

public void getValue(){
    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++){
        System.out.println(value % 10);
        value /= 10;
    }
}

int count = 1;
int value;


}
```

**Tester Class**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class SeparatorTester {

public static void main(String[] args){

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int userInput = sc.nextInt();
Separator s = new Separator(userInput); 

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `main` method, you read a number into `userInput`,
and then create a new `Separator` from it,
and then you do nothing else.
None of these operations print anything,
that's why there is no output.
You could add this line to get some output:

```
s.getValue();
```

But your program doesn't actually work.
For `userInput = 123`,
the program outputs `3`.
I don't think that's what you wanted.

> I'm writing a program that will read in a line of integers and will print them out in reverse order on separate lines.

This sounds like that if user enters for example `13 51 47` on a single line, then you want to print the numbers in reverse order, each on a separate line, like this:

```
47
51
13
```

To implement this, it's easiest to use a stack, for example:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("13 51 47");
ArrayDeque<Integer> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    stack.push(scanner.nextInt());
}

while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println(stack.pop());
}
```

On the other hand, your implementation contradicts with your description,
it looks more like you might want to *reverse the digits*,
for example if the input is 123, you want to print 321.
A simpler implementation for that instead of your `Separator` class could be:

```
int reverse(int value) {
    int work = 0;
    while (value > 0) {
        work *= 10;
        work += value % 10;
        value /= 10;
    }
    return work;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u call the print commnad inside a method u need to call the method to start printing.. u create Separator object now this object need to call the method .
**s.getValue()**

btw if u want to print all integers in revers u should not cut the number when value %10 == 0 in that way u cut some of the digits and u could not print them in ur method ..
try this :

```
let say u got value 4567

x=0
y=0
result=0

x=value/10

y=value -x >> now y got the the number 7

result =result*10+y
>> now result got 7

value = value/10
```

all this in loops unteel value/10 ==0 && value%10 ==0

after the second iteretion result got the number 76 ... after 765 and etc

when value /10 ==0 its mean he got 1 digit

when value /10 ==0 and value%10 ==0 its mean value =0 and its mean u cut all digits from value